# How to add a signalr pipeline module in Azure mobile service

Tags: c#, signalr, azure-mobile-services

I want to add a signalr pipeline module as described [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#hubpipeline).

The article says to add code to `startup.cs` file but I don't have such a class in my mobile service. Also, the code uses `GlobalHost` which from my (limited) experience does not really work inside a mobile service.

I tried adding this line in `WebApiConfig` class but it doesn't work:

```
GlobalHost.HubPipeline.AddModule(new LoggingPipelineModule());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find the answer anywhere so I dug in the mobile services signalr assembly and found the solution.

To add your own module, add the following code to `WebApiConfig`:

```
var hubPipeline = config.DependencyResolver.GetSignalRDependencyResolver().Resolve<IHubPipeline>();
hubPipeline.AddModule(new MyModule());
```